# Why does relocation with the maven shade plugin not work?

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, guava, maven-shade-plugin

I am having [some trouble](https://github.com/internetarchive/ia-hadoop-tools/issues/6) running a Hadoop job that includes a newer version of Guava than the one that is included in the Hadoop distribution (CDH 5.2). This is a known problem. I try to solve it [by shading the libraries](https://github.com/rjoberon/ia-hadoop-tools/commit/4a5f05642d820af5451e9cbc46af4ac999f3c34f) using the Maven shade plugin. Therefore, I added the following lines to my `pom.xml`:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>com.google</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>thirdparty.com.google</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Unfortunately, the shading seems not to work. When I extract the uber-JAR there is no folder `thirdparty/com/google` but still the folder `com/google`.

Does someone have an idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: it is  avaibable for me, you can try it again then check the generated jar whether it takes effect. <br/>  <configuration>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>shade.com.google</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me:

```
<relocations>
   <relocation>
     <pattern>com.google.</pattern>
     <shadedPattern>thirdparty.com.google.</shadedPattern>
   </relocation>
 </relocations>
```

note the dot at the end of the pattern.

Comment: How would one import this within a .scala file? import thirdparty.com.google. does not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to specify explicit artifactSet::includes under your `<configuration>` section:

```
    <configuration>
        <artifactSet>
            <includes>
                <include>com.google.guava:*</include>
                ...
            </includes>
        </artifactSet>
        <relocations>
        ...
```

Comment: Doing this requires you to then specify every inclusion.  It also did not fix the shading issue.

Comment: An empty `<artifactSet></artifactSet>` made it work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you need to refer to the package name in the relocation rule, not the maven groupId, I'm using rx v1 in my lib and don't want to pollute the user's namespace with it, the pom.xml section below rewrites the bytecode, so the final uberjar will have rx, but renamed (shaded.rx).

[shade relocation doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html)

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>rx</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>shaded.rx</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```