# Spark error with google/guava library: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.refreshAfterWrite

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple `spark` project - in which in the `pom.xml` the dependencies are only the basic `scala`, `scalatest`/`junit`, and `spark`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When attempting to run a basic `spark` program the `SparkSession` init fails on this line:

```
 SparkSession.builder.master(master).appName("sparkApp").getOrCreate
```

Here is the output / error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
18/04/07 18:06:15 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder
.refreshAfterWrite(JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)
Lcom/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder;
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:73)

at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:293)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:283)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:260)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:789)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:774)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:647)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2424)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2424)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2424)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:295)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2516)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:918)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:910)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:910)
```

I have run `spark` locally many dozens of times on other projects, what might be wrong with this simple one?  Is there a dependency on `$HADOOP_HOME` environment variable or similar?

**Update**  By downgrading the `spark` version to `2.0.1` I was able to compile. That does *not* fix the problem (we need newer) version. But it helps point out the source of the problem

**Another update**  In a *different* project the hack to downgrade to `2.0.1` does help - i.e. execution proceeds *further* : but then when writing out to **`parquet`** a similar exception does happen.

```
8/05/07 11:26:11 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2741.0 (TID 2618)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.build(Lcom/google/common/cache/CacheLoader;)Lcom/google/common/cache/LoadingCache;
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.createCache(CodecPool.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.<clinit>(CodecPool.java:74)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.CodecFactory$BytesCompressor.<init>(CodecFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.CodecFactory.getCompressor(CodecFactory.java:169)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:303)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetFileFormat.scala:562)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs due to version mismatch between Google's guava library and Spark.
Spark shades guava but many libraries use guava. You can try Shading the Guava dependencies as per this post.
[Apache-Spark-User-List](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Guava-dependency-issue-td32115.html#a32127)

Comment: I mentioned in the post and showed in the `pom.xml` that no additional  /outside-of-spark dependencies were added. This question is specifically about what *inside* of spark/spark-dependencies is causing this to happen.

Comment: Guava comes bundled with many dependencies hence the solution to Shade it in your pom.xml file

Comment: Your comment did not actually answer my comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

Adding shade plugin to your pom file and relocating google package can resolve this issue.

More information can found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42400087/1039149) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535909/why-does-relocation-with-the-maven-shade-plugin-not-work)

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <relocations>
                <relocation>
                    <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>shade.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

If this also doesn't help then adding guava library of version 15.0 works nicely. The reason of this work around is in dependencyManagement. The nice SO answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44020271/1039149)

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error in spring boot : java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilderSpec
com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.build()Lcom/google/common/cache/Cache

The issue is due to "com.google.guava:guava" api. In springboot this api comes under some other api might be "spring-boot-starter-web" or "springfox-swagger2" api so we need to first exclude guava api from springfox-swagger2 jar and need to add updated version of guava api.spring-data-mongodb

**Solution:**
1. add guava dependency on the top of all the dependency so that springboot can ge the latest version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Find out the spring boot dependecy where artifactId: "guava" included then exlude "guava" artifact from that dependency and then add the guava dependency like above.

Comment: I'm not using `spring boot`: can you explain why you added this answer?